# Question on limits, continuity and Integrability

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Given a function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,2]$ such that
  $f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x =\frac{n}{n+1}(n=1,2,3,...) \\ 1 & elsewhere\end{cases}$

Does the limit of above function exist at $x=1$? If yes, is the function continuous? Also, is the function Reimann Integrable? If yes what is the value of the ${\int_{0}^2 f(x)\mathrm dx}$

Acoording to me, $\lim_{x\to 1+}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 1-}$ is not defined because in the interval $(1-d)$ there are countably infinite $\frac{n}{n+1}$ where $f=0$ and uncountable other numbers where $f=1$. So, the limit does not exist at 1

But the answer given is $\lim_{x\to 1}=0$ but f is not continuous as $f(1)=1$.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Try computing the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. If they are equal, then the limit exists and is equal to the $\limsup$. For continuity, just apply the definition.

Comment: Well in every interval $(1-d, 1+d)$ there will be some numbers of the form $\frac {n}{n+1}$ and some numbers that are not of that form.  What are the consequences of that?

Comment: Hmm.... was the question $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x) = 0$.  That is true.  But if $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = 1$ then you and I both made the exact same error and .... I don't see what it is.  I am sure you and I are correct.

Comment: No, the question is whether $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 0$. But I don't get how $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x) = 0$ is true. For $x \gt 1$, x can never be of the form $\frac{n}{n+1}$

Comment: Oops.  I transposed the values of $0$ and $1$.  I thought it was $f(x) = 0$ if $x \ne \frac n{n+1}$.  At any event $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x) = f(w)$ where $w \ne \frac n{n+1}$.  I thought that was $0$ but I see that it was $1$.

Comment: I'm stumped.  I'm not saying that you and I can't both be wrong (we could be) but I really do think you and I are (careless dyslexic transposing of $0$ and $1$ aside) both correct.

Comment: Even I think we are right, but based on the assumption that $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 0$ (apparently not an assumption for the author), author has further proved the function to be Reimann Integrable and calculated the required integral and I am scratching my head thinking of how any of it makes sense.

Comment: The "answer given" is wrong and U R Right.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing that screams in my ear is $\frac n{n+1} \to 1$.

To put that in useful terms of the actual definition of limits that means for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ so that $n>N\implies \frac n{n+1}\in (1-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$.

But there are points in that interval that *aren't* of the form.  That is.  for $w\in (\frac n{n+1}, \frac {n+1}{n+1} \subset (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$ then $w \ne \frac {m}{m+1}$ for any natural $m$.

So for any $\epsilon: \frac 12 > \epsilon > 0$ then there will by an $w = \frac n{n+1} \in (1-\epsilon,1 +\epsilon)$ where $f(w) = 0$.  And there will be a $y\ne \frac m{m+1}$ for any natural $m$ where $f(y) =1$.

Now if $|a-f(y)|=|a-1|< \epsilon < \frac 12$ then $|a-f(w)|=|a-0| > \frac 12 > \epsilon$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x) \ne a$.  And if $|a-f(y)|=|a-1|\ge \epsilon$ then $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x) \ne a$.

So there is no $a \in \mathbb R$ where $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = a$.